# Will WaitForSingleObject cause a context switch when waiting with a timeout time of zero?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi

Will `WaitForSingleObject` (or `WaitForMultipleObjects`) cause a context switch when waiting for an event with a timeout time of zero? (`Sleep(0)` will yield a threads time-slice immediately as far as I know.)

Now, regarding `WaitForSingle|MultipleObject` and Event handles. If WaitFor*Object actually needs to wait, it would obviously yield the rest of its time-slice. However, there are two cases where the API does *not* need to wait:

- Either the event is signalled, in which case it can return with `WAIT_OBJECT_0`
- Or the state of the event doesn't matter as I specified a wait time of zero, in which case it can return immediately, either with `WAIT_OBJECT_0` or `WAIT_TIMEOUT`

Now, given this, will `WaitForSingleObject` cause a thread context switch if a timeout time of zero is supplied?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the Windows Research Kernel and some simple reverse-engineering of `KeWaitForSingleObject`, the answer is **no**. Looking at the WRK, the internal timer's due time is checked before `KiSwapThread` is called, making sure the function returns immediately if the object isn't signaled.

Answer (score 5):

Now it seems I kind of found an answer while writing up the question -- here's what I **assume** from the available docs:

The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687025%28VS.85%29.aspx) states the following:

> dwMilliseconds [in]
>
> The time-out interval, in milliseconds. If a nonzero value is
>   specified, the function waits until
>   the specified objects are signaled or
>   the interval elapses. **If
>   dwMilliseconds is zero, the function
>   does not enter a wait state if the
>   specified objects are not signaled**; it
>   always returns immediately. If
>   dwMilliseconds is INFINITE, the
>   function will return only when the
>   specified objects are signaled.

I would take this to imply that it *also* does not enter a wait state if the *objects are signaled* and I would interpret "*does not enter a wait state*" as "no context switch happens".